# How to use the DropDownList's SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, event-handling

I have two `DropDownList`s in my webform and when I select a value in the first dropdownlist, I would like a related value to be automatically selected in the second dropdownlist.

This is what I currently have:

```
    <table>   
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbmanu" runat="server" Text="Furniture Manufacturer : 
                   "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddmanu" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="Sql_fur_model_manu"    
                    DataTextField="manufacturer" DataValueField="manufacturer" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="ddmanu_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Sql_fur_model_manu" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conStr %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [manufacturer] FROM 
                     [furniture_manufacturer]">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbtype" runat="server" Text="Furniture Type : 
                        "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddtype" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                   </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

Code Behind :

```
protected void ddmanu_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "select furniture from furniture_model where manufacturer='" + 
    ddmanu.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    DataTable dt = Select(query);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ddtype.DataSource = dt;
    ddtype.DataTextField = "manufacturer";
    ddtype.DataValueField = "furniture";
    ddtype.DataBind(); 
}
```

Comment: What happens with the code you currently have?

Answer (score 9):

You should add AutoPostBack="true" to DropDownList1

```
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddmanu" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                    DataSourceID="Sql_fur_model_manu"    
                    DataTextField="manufacturer" DataValueField="manufacturer" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="ddmanu_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 5):

The most basic way you can do this in SelectedIndexChanged events of DropDownLists. Check this code..

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="224px"
        AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList> 


protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Load DropDownList2

}
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Load DropDownList3
}
```

Comment: It's really clear Ketan, two drobdownlists, changing the first one fires the SelectedIndexChanged event. in the event handler "DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" yo need to load the second dropdownlist based on the value of first dropdownlist...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the culprit:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

DataTable dt = Select(query);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

ddtype.DataSource = dt;
```

I don't know what that code is supposed to do, but it looks like you want to create an `SqlDataReader` for that, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566430/drop-down-list-not-binding-with-sqldatareader) and all over the web if you search for "SqlCommand DropDownList DataSource":

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
ddtype.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Or you can create a `DataTable` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105265/dropdownlist-datasource):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

SqlDataAdapter listQueryAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable listTable = new DataTable();
listQueryAdapter.Fill(listTable);

ddtype.DataSource = listTable;
```