# Add and populate input(number) after selecting dropdown

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a input textbox (type=number) and a dropdown.

The dropdown is attached with a data source to my database.

How can i auto add the dropdown value to the input textbox after selecting one.

The input textbox may contain a number already, so i need to combine and add up, not replacing the current number.

I hope to do it from codebehind, is it possible?

Comment: You need to learn about how to use SelectedIndexChanged event of the dropdown. Using that you can perform this in code behind. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/092589/working-with-dropdownlist-slectedindexchanged-event/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the DropDownList's SelectedIndexChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438389/how-to-use-the-dropdownlists-selectedindexchanged-event)