# ASP.NET dropdownlist selectedIndexChanged not getting triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to create a form as part of a website. In the form the user is shown a dropdownlist with serveral options. If the user chooses the "Other" option, then they should be presented with a text box to fill the description of the "other" choice.

My idea was to hide the div that contains the text box and enable it when the user changes the dropdown list choice to "other".

I am having an issue where in asp.net the dropdownlist "selectedindexchanged" event is not being triggered. Below is the HTML code and the cs code.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/master/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="form.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project.forms.form" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="menu" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Banner" runat="server">
        <img src="../../image.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" />
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
         
      <h2 class="branding_orange">Form</h2>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" name="warningDiv" style="margin-top:10px" id="warningDiv" role="alert" runat="server">
            <p name="warningMsg" id="warningMsg" runat="server"></p>
        </div>
      <form id="compliantForm" role="form" class="form" runat="server" data-toggle="validator" onsubmit="return validation();">
          <div class="row">
               .
               .
               .
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="person-submitting-select">Is the person submitting this complaint an: <b style="color:red">*</b></label>&nbsp;
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="cboPersonSubmitting" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "True" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="select" Value="0" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Employee" Value="1" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Customer" Value="2" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="3" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
    
                  </div>
    
              </div>
    .
    .
    .
    .
        
    </asp:Content>
    
    <asp:Content ID="Content6" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace Project.forms
{
    public partial class form : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cboPersonSubmitting.AutoPostBack = true;
            warningDiv.Visible = false;
            warningMsg.InnerHtml = "";
            
            
        }
        .
        .
        .

        protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cboPersonSubmitting.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {
                whoSubmittingDiv.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                whoSubmittingDiv.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe check if the validation javascript function is triggered and it inibhits your postback

Comment: Most of the time the event don't fire because you have forgot the autopostback property :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438389/how-to-use-the-dropdownlists-selectedindexchanged-event/19438520 .
But this is not the case here. in fact it should work. May you had a break point and see if it didn't fire? 
Or Write something into a label before the if. And move that dropdown out of the form just to see if it's not related.

Comment: @DragandDrop I have added a breakpoint inside the "OnSelectedIndexChanged" func and noticed that it doesn't reach there when the item is changed in the dropdown list. In regards to taking the dropdownlist outside of the form, i need it to be inside the form as the value of the dropdownlist will be taken in the form and validated.

Comment: Debuging often require isolation. It's easier to know if a part is broken when it's tested solo. That's part of the [mre] guideline, that I recommend every day out side of Stackoverflow. If it's the form fault we will need information on how to reproduce that issue with the validation js code. Remove every till it works. Add things back one by one. till it break.

Comment: I think that you have to check the javascript code, if it returns false, form submit will be stopped.

Comment: @Saledan How can i check that in ASP.NET?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.Your code is the following "form id="compliantForm" role="form" class="form" runat="server" data-toggle="validator" onsubmit="return validation();">" ... so you add onsubmit="return validation();", so you should know where the javascript code (and validation function) is.

Comment: maybe javascript is included on Site1.Master page

Comment: Keep in mind the page is a content holder. Meaning it inherits from the master page

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, you can try the following code to show textbox when you choose Other in the dropdownlist.

Html:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="person-submitting-select">Is the person submitting this complaint an: <b style="color:red">*</b></label>&nbsp;
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="cboPersonSubmitting" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboPersonSubmitting_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="select" Value="0" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Employee" Value="1" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Customer" Value="2" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="3" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                      <div class="Submitdiv" id="thediv" runat="server" visible="false"> 
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                      </div>
    
                  </div>
    
              </div>
    </form>
```

C# code:

```
 protected void cboPersonSubmitting_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cboPersonSubmitting.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {
                thediv.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                thediv.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Result:

[image]